# how to predict probabilities for a model fitted with glmmTMB function

Tags: r, regression, glm, predict, glmmtmb

i used the below code but i get an error for po.gp since it is a generalized poisson model fitted with glmmTMB package. i get the error:

```
#MODEL COMPARISONS
library(pscl)
po.p <- predprob(model.p) %>% colMeans
po.nb <- predprob(model.nb) %>% colMeans
po.gp <- predprob(model.gp) %>% colMeans

df <- data.frame(x = 0:max(na.omit(bo$Grav)), Poisson = po.p, 
                 NegBin = po.nb, Gen_Poisson = po.gp)

obs <- table(bo$Grav) %>% prop.table() %>% data.frame #Observed
names(obs) <- c("x", 'Observed')

p1 <- predict(linear) %>% round() %>% table %>% prop.table %>% data.frame #for OLS
names(p1) <- c('x', 'OLS')

tmp <- merge(p1, obs, by = 'x', all = T)
tmp$x <- as.numeric(as.character(tmp$x))

comb <- merge(tmp, df, by = 'x', all = T)
comb[is.na(comb)] <- 0

comb2 <- comb[1:11, ] #just for the first 11 results, including zero

mm <- melt(comb2, id.vars = 'x', value.name = 'prob', variable.name = 'Model')
mm <- filter(mm, Model != "OLS") #can include the linear model too if you want
#the SAS note does not, so I am not including it

ggplot(mm, aes(x = x, y = prob, group = Model, col = Model)) +
  geom_line(aes(lty = Model), lwd = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Number of pregnancies", y = 'Probability',
       title = "Models for number of pregnancies") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'blue', 'red', 'green')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid', 'dotted', 'dotted', 'dotted')) +
  theme(legend.position=c(.2, .80), axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

i was trying to predict and plot probabilities from a Generalized Poisson model fitted with glmmTMB package in order to compare it with other count models but the function predprob doesn't work for glmmTMB package but i am looking an appropriate function to use.

Comment: Have you looked into package `sjPlot`? `plot_model(model_fit, type = "pred")` should give you what you need, and the aesthetics are modifiable through ggplot2

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full drop-in replacement for `predprob`, but you can use `VGAM::dgenpois1()` to generate the corresponding probabilities. (To check the correspondence between `glmmTMB` and `VGAM`'s parameterizations, see `?glmmTMB::family_glmmTMB`, which states that the variance-mean relationship is `V = mu*exp(eta)`; this corresponds to `VGAM`'s `dgenpois1()` function.

```r
library(VGAM)
library(glmmTMB)
set.seed(101)
z <- rgenpois1(1000, meanpar = exp(2), dispind = 2)
m <- glmmTMB(z ~ 1, data = data.frame(z_nb), family = genpois)


xvec <- 0:23
probs <- dgenpois1(xvec, meanpar = exp(predict(m)[1]),
          dispind = sigma(m), log = FALSE)


par(las = 1)
plot(prop.table(table(z)))
points(xvec, probs, col = 2, pch = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it and/or upvote it.